# redirect from one port to another

Tags: python, redirect, port, lighttpd

heres what im trying to do

i have a vps with a mumble server on it and a domain name, the server uses lighttpd
i want my users to be able to use "mumble.mydomain.net" to get to the server but i dont want them to be required to use the default port, yet i cant use the default port

so heres what im trying to do
a user will type mumble.mydomain.net and leave 64738 as the port
the server will receive the request on port 64738 and then will redirect the connection to another port, lets say 64739.

is this possible or am i dreaming in colors

solution in python, java, lighttpd, or anything else is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Why can't the user just enter "mumble.mydomain.net:64739" if the mumble server is running on 64739? If you really do require the user to not enter the port, and do not want your mumble server to listen on 64738, you may be able to use lighttpd to reverse proxy 64738 to 64739 on your server. See the [mod_proxy](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModProxy) documentation for more information. You would want to reverse proxy to host 127.0.0.1 and port 64739.